# Suggest me specific book for studying scattering theory and special functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, scattering

I am doing msc physics. And we are studying major part of scattering theory. I used *Quantum Mechanics* by Davydov, Griffiths, etc, to study scattering theory. But I am not understanding it properly, hence I want a specific book which will explain scattering theory very clearly.

Comment: Hi dking, Phys.SE only allows a limited number of resource recommendation questions, because they tend to be e.g. _primarily opinion-based_ and list-questions. I'm closing this a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Comment: Sure no problem. It would be a nice if you could help me with my query.

Comment: I find [the textbook by taylor](http://www.amazon.com/Scattering-Theory-Nonrelativistic-Collisions-Engineering/dp/0486450139) gives a very clear and systematic treatment of non-relativistic scattering.

Comment: Ok thanks i will go through it. If it becomes available.

Comment: Another mistaken question close... you got an upvote as a protest against the hostile robo-closing behavior of the site.

Comment: @peter yeah you are right, I was asking a specific question which has not been asked before. And it was very important. Btw if you know any book please tell me in the comment. thank you

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this question is much more specific than the one asking for a general book about QM. And as we have the new books policy, such questions are allowed now. So this unilateral closure was not appropriate, voting to reopen.